# Accessing value assigned in one function inside another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access values from one function inside another. Both functions are at the same scope, not nested.

I've tried to use only one function ComponentDidMount() and increased the scope of the outer query so that the value is accessible inside. It works but keeps giving an error in the console, yet the display is correct. I think it's because I'm use same reference to multiple things. But if I reduce the scope, while still keeping it one function, it doesn't work. I think it's just the same as creating two functions and not being able to access the value inside another. But I don't understand, although I setState of the value inside the first function. Why does it return to default in the second, which I initialised in the constructor?

This is what I have now. Please note that the ComponentWillMount can be any other function.

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    let query = [];
    this.unsub = this.props.firebase.users().doc(this.props.firebase.userId()).get().then(doc => {
        query.push(doc.data().LinkedUsername)
        const lU = this.props.firebase.users().where("email", "==", query[0])
        lU.get().then(snapshot => {
            // console.log(snapshot.docs[0].id)
            this.setState({queryId: snapshot.docs[0].id});

            console.log(this.state.queryId)

        })
    })
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({loading: true});

    console.log(this.state.queryId)

    this.unsubscribe = this.props.firebase
        .users().doc(this.props.firebase.userId()).collection('tasks')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            let items = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc =>
                (doc.data().status === false) ?
                    items.push({...doc.data(), uid: doc.id})
                    :
                    null
            );
            this.setState({
                items,
                loading: false,
            });
        });
}
```

Note the console locations. The first console returns the desired value, but second doesn't. It returns either undefined or what I assign when I initialise it in the constructor, like below

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: false,
        items: [],
        // queryId: null
    };
    this.classes = props;
}
```

If I do below, it gives desired output on the screen, but keeps throwing same error thousands of times in the console.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    console.log(this.state.queryId)
    let query = [];
    this.unsub = this.props.firebase.users().doc(this.props.firebase.userId()).get().then(doc => {
        query.push(doc.data().LinkedUsername)
        const lU = this.props.firebase.users().where("email", "==", query[0])
        lU.get().then(snapshot => {
            // console.log(snapshot.docs[0].id)
            this.setState({queryId: snapshot.docs[0].id});
            console.log(this.state.queryId)
            this.unsubscribe = this.props.firebase
                .users().doc(this.props.firebase.userId()).collection('tasks')
                .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                    let items = [];
                    snapshot.forEach(doc =>
                        (doc.data().status === false) ?
                            items.push({...doc.data(), uid: doc.id})
                            :
                            null
                    );
                    this.setState({
                        items,
                        loading: false,
                    });
                });
        })
    })
}
```

But if I do below, it doesn't. check the difference in the placement of brackets on second last and third last line.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: false,
        items: [],
        // queryId: null
    };
    this.classes = props;
}
```

If I do below, it gives desired output on the screen but keeps throwing same error thousands of times in the console.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({loading: true});
    console.log(this.state.queryId)
    let query = [];
    this.unsub = this.props.firebase.users().doc(this.props.firebase.userId()).get().then(doc => {
        query.push(doc.data().LinkedUsername)
        const lU = this.props.firebase.users().where("email", "==", query[0])
        lU.get().then(snapshot => {
            // console.log(snapshot.docs[0].id)
            this.setState({queryId: snapshot.docs[0].id});
            console.log(this.state.queryId)
        })
    })
    this.unsubscribe = this.props.firebase
        .users().doc(this.props.firebase.userId()).collection('tasks')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            let items = [];
            snapshot.forEach(doc =>
                (doc.data().status === false) ?
                    items.push({...doc.data(), uid: doc.id})
                    :
                    null
            );
            this.setState({
                items,
                loading: false,
            });
        });
}
```

Actual results

```
undefined index.js:43
Qz1mFFBgPrUFPfO1YFqVxfVpAbE2 index.js:36
```

Expected results

```
Qz1mFFBgPrUFPfO1YFqVxfVpAbE2 index.js:43
Qz1mFFBgPrUFPfO1YFqVxfVpAbE2 index.js:36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` gets called after initial render.
And `setState()` is async call.

So basically, when your `componentWillMount()` `setState()` called and state value was updated, `componentDidMount()` was already called.

Avoid calling or using apis in constructor or `componentWillMount()`

Your network requests should be in `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Thanks, Ravi. The answer is helpful. I'm trying to fix it, keeping your comment in mind. Meanwhile, I would appreciate you could explain it with an example code which helps me fix this. issue.

Comment: What exact error you get on console when using all code in componentDidMount() ??

Comment: ``` index.js:1446 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.``` This!

Comment: And this error occurs when I write it like the snippet below this line in the original post. "If I do below, it gives desired output on the screen, but keeps throwing same error thousands of times in the console." Yet it gives me the correct output.

Comment: index.js:1446 -> This must be a statement in render which consists of key={/something/}. You are getting this something duplicate for multiple childs of array.

Comment: Yes Sure. "},
        d = function d(e, t) {
      if ("undefined" != typeof console) {
        var n = console[e];
        "function" == typeof n && (console[e] = function () {
          try {
            var e = arguments[0];
            "string" == typeof e && c.length > 0 && t(e, c[c.length - 1]);
          } catch (e) {
            setTimeout(function () {
              throw e;
            });
          }

          return n.apply(this, arguments);
        });
      }
    };" This code is from one of the internal libraries I believe. Return line is 1446

Comment: To work around this I thought to return value from one function so that I can use it outside in another. But as mentioned above, it's not working as well.

Comment: Is line 1446 inside render function ??

Comment: If yes, then please attach code around that line. It is irrespective of your third party library. Main issue here is key violation in your render function. Which you might have used in Array.map format inside render function

Comment: No, it's not inside render. If you don't mind, I've posted the folder here. Both Index.js and Album.js are being discussed here. map is used in album.js. And issue is in index. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NovRgSA_T2tPQTfosD4qzSmzWzqt-nlc?usp=sharing

Comment: Try replacing this <Grid key={card. uid} item sm={ 6 } md={ 4 } lg={ 3 }>   with just immediate line containing map in Album.js              (Hope uid is unique in your cards elements)

Comment: Thanks Ravi. That worked. :D You're a star. Yes uid is unique.

Comment: It's my pleasure helping you

Answer (score 0):

As @Ravi said, you should not call your network request inside the `componentWillMount`. You can call network request inside `componentDidMount` safely.

In your first code snippet, you are calling `this.setState()` in the `componentWillMount()` and setting state after the response from firebase. It would take time to get data from the firebase and set state after getting response.

`componentDidMount()` will be called immediately as soon as the component is mounted. As it would take a while to get the data from the firebase and set it to the state in `componentWillMount()`, the second `console.log()` will give you `undefined` or whatever you have assign when you initialize it in the constructor.

In you second code snippet, you have your constructor like:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            items: [],
            // queryId: null
        };
        this.classes = props;
}
```

As you have commented the `queryId` in the constructor, and logging it in the `componentDidMount()`, it would throw an error or give you `undefined` in the console as it has not been initialized in the constructor.

As React/ReactNative is a declarative framework i.e. you only tell React/ReactNative what do you need, without bothering about how to do it, you can follow the following approach for network request and when state changes, all state values will be updated inside the whole component:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            items: [],
            queryId: null
        };
 }


componentDidMount = () => {
       //your network request
       fetch('fetch_url')
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ //making result to be globally accessible
                loading: false,
                items: response.items,
                queryId: response.queryId
            });
       })
       .catch((error) => {
               //handle error
       })
}
```

However, if you want to perform multiple requests, one after another, then you can use `async/await` or you can make a chain of `then` statements like below:

```
fetch('fetch_url')
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ //making result to be globally accessible
                loading: false,
                items: response.items,
                queryId: response.queryId
            }); 
            return response.queryId;
       })
       .then((response) => { //'queryId' returned from the upper 'then'
            //other operations       
       })
       .catch((error) => {
               //handle error
       })
```

Comment: Thanks, Ajay. This looks promising. I did try a chain of .then but I believe I wasn't using it correctly. I tried a suggestion from Ravi. It worked. But I'll definitely keep this in consideration for the future. Thanks a ton.